# Angular 2.0.0 [hidden] doesn't run in some cases

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've layout with `[hidden]`:

```
<main id="content" class="content view-animate fade-up" role="main">
    <div [hidden]="!preloader.isLoading">
          <img class="absolute-center" src="/assets/img/cube.svg" alt="Loading..."/>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="preloader.isLoading">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
```

I've service to handle this:

```
export class PreloaderService {
    private _isLoading: boolean = false;
    constructor(router:Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            console.log('event',event);
            if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                this._isLoading = true;
            }
            if(event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError || event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
                this._isLoading = false;
            }
        });
    }
    get isLoading() {
        return this._isLoading;
    }
}
```

Problem: when I'm logging in with Facebook account, I see loader, then my target page. If I logging out right after that, and log in with FB again, `NavigationEnd` event fired, value of `preloader.isLoading` changed to `false`, but loading picture still visible. If I click something(in menu near page area for example) - page became visible and loader dissapear.
If I reload page after logging out, then page loading will processed normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like some callback runs outside Angulars zone.

```
export class PreloaderService {

    private _isLoading: boolean = false;

    constructor(router:Router, cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { // <<<=== modified
        router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            console.log('event',event);
            if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                this._isLoading = true;
                cdRef.detectChanges(); // <<<=== added
            }
            if(event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError || event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
                this._isLoading = false;
                cdRef.detectChanges(); // <<<=== added
            }
        });
    }
    get isLoading() {
        return this._isLoading;
    }
}
```

It's better to use `zone.run()` where the callback calls Angular2 code outside the zone but that code is not contained in your question.

Above code should at least work to verify that my assumption is correct.

Comment: getting error `no provider for ChangeDetectorRef`, but it works perfect with `ApplicationRef` and `tick()`. But how to avoid this injects? It's connected with FB callbacks?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it's in a service. `ChangeDetectorRef` is only available in components.

Comment: If `router.navigate(...)` is called from code that runs outside Angulars zone, this can cause weird behavior. I'd suggest you try to figure out where this happens and move the execution back to Angulars zone using `zone.run(...)`.

Comment: you are right, `router.navigate()` used inside `FB.login()` callback. Thanks a lot.